# Json property and instance variable both comes on request

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a pojo class for a json property like:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class ItemsListPost {

    @JsonProperty("order_product_id")
    private int orderProductId;
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private int quantity;

    public int getOrderProductId() {
        return orderProductId;
    }

    public void setOrderProductId(int orderProductId) {
        this.orderProductId = orderProductId;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

I set the value for this class and try to retrieve the json response using

```
String requestShipment = objMapper.writeValueAsString(shp);
            System.out.println(requestShipment);
```

It shows me double output for orderProductId like this:

```
{  
         "order_product_id":106,
         "orderProductId":106,
         "quantity":1
      }
```

How to prevent from this situation on OrderProductId I need order_product_id only.

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct imports. Just tried this myself and it worked as expected? `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
`

Comment: I already imported these two liens                                                         import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

Comment: Try changing your imports to the following. If required also change your dependency;
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;`  If you are using Maven use the following dependency `<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution . I am using 1.7.* jackson all for resolve this problem I put the  @JsonProperty("order_product_id") in the getter method()